# Counting unique subsets of data efficiently

Tags: r, data.table

I have a relatively large dataset that I wouldn't qualify as 'big data'. It's around 3 to 5 million rows; because of the size I'm using the `data.table` library to do analysis.

The dataset (named `df`, which is a `data.table` structure) composition can essentially be broken into:

1. n identify fields, hereafter `ID_1`, `ID_2`, ..., `ID_n`, some of which are numeric and some of which are character vector.
2. m categorical variables, hereafter `C_1`, ..., `C_m`, all of which are character vector and have very few values apiece (2 in one, 3 in another, etc...)
3. 2 measurement variables, `M_1`, and `M_2`, both numeric.

A subset of data is identified by `ID_1` through `ID_n`, has a full set of all values of `C_1` through `C_m`, and has a range of values of `M_1` and `M_2`. A subset of data consists of 126 records.

I need to accurately count the unique sets of data and, because of the size of the data, I would like to know if there already exists a much more efficient way to do this. (Why roll my own if other, much smarter, people have done it already?)

I've already done a fair amount of Google work to arrive at the method below.

What I've done is to use the `ht` package (https://github.com/nfultz/ht) so that I can use a data frame as a hash value (using digest in the background).

I paste together the ID fields to create a new, single column, hereafter referred to as `ID`, which resembles...

```
ID = "ID1:ID2:...:IDn"
```

Then I loop through each unique set of identifiers and then, using just the subset data frame of `C_1` through `C_m`, `M_1`, and `M_2` (126 rows of data), hash the value / increment the hash.

Afterwards I'm taking that information and putting it back into the data frame.

```
# Create the hash structure
datasets <- ht()
# Declare the fields which will denote a subset of data
uniqueFields <- c("C_1",..."C_m","M_1","M_2")
# Create the REPETITIONS field in the original data.table structure
df[,REPETITIONS := 0]
# Create the KEY field in the original data.table structure
df[,KEY := ""]

# Use the updateHash function to fill datasets
updateHash <- function(val){
    key <- df[ID==val, uniqueFields, with=FALSE]
    if (isnull(datasets[key])) {
        # If this unique set of data doesn't already exist in datasets...
        datasets[key] <- list(val)
    } else {
        # If this unique set of data does already exist in datasets...
        datasets[key] <- append(datasets[key],val)
    }
}

# Loop through the ID fields. I've explored using apply;
# this vector is around 10-15K long. This version works.
for (id in unique(df$ID)) {
    updateHash(id)
}

# Now update the original data.table structure so the analysis can
# be done. Again, I could use the R apply family, this version works.
for(dataset in ls(datasets)){
    IDS <- unlist(datasets[[dataset]]$val)
    # For this set of information, how many times was it repeated?
    df[ID%in%IDS, REPETITIONS := length(datasets[[dataset]]$val)]
    # For this set, what is a unique identifier?
    df[ID%in%IDS, KEY := dataset]
}
```

This does what I want to, though not blindingly fast. I now have the capability to present some neat analysis revolving around variability in datasets to people who care about it. I don't like that it's hackey and, one way or another, I'm going to clean this up and make it better. Before I do that I want to do my final due diligence and see if it's simply my Google Fu failing me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you could give us an example of your data, it would be easier to help you and make your problem reproducible. Could you please add the output of `dput(head(df,20))` to your question? And also how should the output looks like?

Comment: Mr_Z, unfortunately I can't add the output (it's on a standalone network) and can't get too specific with the data. If absolutely necessary I'll throw in some code to mock up a dataset.

The output of this algorithm should be that every unique ID field has a number of REPETITIONS associated. That number is *not* the number of times the ID is seen (that would be one) but rather the number of times the subset of unique fields data is seen repeated for all instances of ID.